# Apply coupon to a customer's subscription based on non-stripe related actions on the site

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am using [django-stripe-payments](https://github.com/eldarion/django-stripe-payments) and can find nothing in the source regarding the application of coupons after a user has been subscribed to a plan. Is it possible to use a coupon to credit a user's subscription after the initial subscription? If not, what is the best alternative?

Specifically, I want to give a user a 100% off coupon for that month after they have taken 5 [site specific actions].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but may not be the best idea.

The way coupons are currently implemented in Stripe, they're applied at the customer level and each customer can only have a single coupon. So if you're already using coupons to offer discounts, the customer will lose whatever discount they currently have. This also means that if you're using Stripe's recently-added multiple subscription capability, *all* of the user's subscriptions would be comped for the month.

Coupons set to "once" can also only be used (as the name implies) once—total—by any given customer, so if this a credit they can earn more than once, you'd have to continually create 100% discount coupons.

The more flexible option here would probably be to simply post a credit via the Stripe API. If you're not otherwise using coupons (and don't plan to), though, you could create a new 100% coupon on a monthly basis.

Comment: I believe coupons can now be applied to subscriptions